# Does Microsoft Bot Framework not support facebook page feeds?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, botframework

Quick question , does microsoft bot framework not support to listen to facebook page's public posts ? from the documentation it only supports FB messenger and FB Workplace , no mention of facebook page's public posts. Please throw some light if my understanding is wrong. if it is true , so the only way to read an FB page's public posts is through some custom code ( like a service ) or can i still leverage Bot Framework to do so ?

looked up official documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#connect-a-bot-to-facebook-workplace

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

There is some newly-added undocumented support for bots to listen for page posts and comments when the bot is mentioned. Please refer to the documentation for the Facebook Pages API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages